# Error when installing Ruby on Rails: "Failed to build gem native extension"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running Crunchbang 11 (Debian-based).

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails, like this:

```
gem install rails --version 4.0.0
```

I get the error "Failed to build gem native extension".

My ruby is version `2.0.0p247`, my RubyGems is `2.0.0`.

What's the issue here?

---

This is the full error output:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/erlkoenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling atomic_reference.c
linking shared-object atomic_reference.so

make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 atomic_reference.so /home/erlkoenig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.10/lib/home/erlkoenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/home/erlkoenig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.10/lib/home/erlkoenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux': No such file or directory
make: *** [install-so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/erlkoenig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/erlkoenig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.10/ext/gem_make.out
```

My `env`:

```
ORBIT_SOCKETDIR=/tmp/orbit-erlkoenig
SSH_AGENT_PID=2695
rvm_bin_path=/home/erlkoenig/.rvm/bin
GEM_HOME=/home/erlkoenig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=9e0343c07c890bd2d60ee6a750f36c6c-1373892339.852749-193038580
IRBRC=/home/erlkoenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/.irbrc
WINDOWID=39845892
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/erlkoenig/.cache/keyring-g6PRS5
MY_RUBY_HOME=/home/erlkoenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247
USER=erlkoenig
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
rvm_path=/home/erlkoenig/.rvm
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-XVmUxMD7LHwi/agent.2651
rvm_prefix=/home/erlkoenig
PATH=/home/erlkoenig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/erlkoenig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/home/erlkoenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/erlkoenig/.rvm/bin:/home/erlkoenig/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/erlkoenig/.rvm/bin:/home/erlkoenig/.scripts:/home/erlkoenig/.scripts/netlogo-5.0.3:/opt/node/bin
MAIL=/var/mail/erlkoenig
PWD=/home/erlkoenig
EDITOR=vim
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=2575
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
rvm_env_string=ruby-2.0.0-p247
rvm_version=1.21.9 (stable)
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/erlkoenig
rvm_ruby_string=ruby-2.0.0-p247
LOGNAME=erlkoenig
GEM_PATH=/home/erlkoenig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247:/home/erlkoenig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-9eOdnYZelY,guid=a5db4ca68e107a48a04c8b8e51e3eef4
DISPLAY=:0.0
RUBY_VERSION=ruby-2.0.0-p247
XAUTHORITY=/home/erlkoenig/.Xauthority
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Comment: try sudo gem install rails --version 4.0.0

Comment: I still get the error.

Comment: You have problem with this dir  `/home/erlkoenig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.10/lib/home/erlkoenig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux` which means either you garbled the log while pasting or you have a mess in PATH

Comment: can you first try gem update --system and them gem install rails --version 4.0.0?

Comment: whoa, `gem update --system` doesn't work, even though I did it before: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
    No such file or directory - getcwd
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Rails 4.0 needs RubyGem version 2.0.3, Just update your system by using following command

```
gem update --system 2.0.3
```

Comment: This did it, thanks. Out of curiosity, may I ask whence you got this piece of information?

Comment: I know this isn't related to this issue in particular, but a Google search of my problem (installing Compass and getting `mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h`) led to this StackOverflow question, so in case anyone is having the same problem, the solution was to get ruby-dev (`sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`.)

Comment: @River Tam A slightly cleaner way to go about that may be to run `rvm requirements`

Comment: @RiverTam I came with the same issue, fresh "yum install ruby" on a CentOS 7 box, and the first gem I threw had the same error. I did "yum install ruby-devel sqlite-devel", and the gem (larch) built fine. Thanks!

Comment: I need to use `sudo` on ubuntu

Answer (score 13):

Run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
```

Then,

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others

Comment: Got this error `Fetching nio4r-2.5.4.gem
Fetching actioncable-6.1.0.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
ilesh:~ silicon$ 
ilesh:~ silicon$ `

Answer (score 10):

Just a follow up ... on different solution...

it may be that you are on a mac and rails cannot find the right compiler for c headers.

just install xcode from apps store / homebrew or go to terminal ...

> $ xcode-select --install

complete the installation and agree on the licensing etc, then ...

> $ sudo gem install rails

Answer (score 7):

Got the same issue when installing rails with the command 
"gem install rails -v 5.1.2" on windows7, solved after installing "MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain" (command ridk install then option 3)..It took a while to finish the installation and then i installed rails without any problem

Comment: I fix it in the same way.

Answer (score 3):

For me this helped:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Comment: I'm on Centos, `yum install ruby-devel` works for me

Answer (score 2):

### I could solve this way

```
rvm use ruby --install --default
```

and then try again.

```
gem install rails --no-document
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
sudo ln -s /bin/mkdir /usr/bin/mkdir
```

I kept encountering this error when I ran `gem install rails -v 5.2.0`:

```
make: /usr/bin/mkdir: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:199: .sitearchdir.-.racc.time] Error 127

make install failed, exit code 2
```

So I ran this command and it fixed it for me:

```
sudo ln -s /bin/mkdir /usr/bin/mkdir
```

Originally found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64653052

Answer (score 1):

Try

`sudo gem install rails --version 2.0`

to install libraries.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone got the error:"Failed to build gem native extension”, while running `sudo gem install rails`, and it said somethings about "nokogiri".

It is possible because you are using the same ruby version as system is using (for mac user). The solution would be install RVM, use RVM to install another ruby version.

So now you have 2 Ruby versions on your machine, RVM will automatically switch to the newly installed version. now, you can run `gem install rails` without error and without `sudo` as well.

Answer (score 1):

i'm running elementary os 5 and what i do is.

```
sudo gem update --system
```

and then try again.

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora 30, I ran into this problem "Failed to build gem native extension". The log error was "gcc: fatal error: cannot read spec file ‘/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1’: No such file or directory". The solution was found [here](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/languages/ruby/gems-installation.html).

```
If you installed all the above, but the extensions would still not compile, you are probably running a Fedora image that misses redhat-rpm-config package. In that case gcc compiler would complain about one of the following:

gcc: error: conftest.c: No such file or directory
gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
To solve this, simply run sudo dnf install redhat-rpm-config.
```

Answer (score 1):

While installing rails 7 when I ran the command

sudo gem install rails

I got the same errors. I tried several suggestions, but in vain. At last one suggestion from the web helped me. I have been asked to run following command :

sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev

and then try again installing rails. Here is the link to that site : https://askubuntu.com/questions/600068/cant-install-a-ruby-package-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

It worked !!!

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error installing rails 7.0.4 because of websocket-driver 0.7.5

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing websocket-driver:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5/ext/websocket-driver
/usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r ./siteconf20221124-7-9o2qxo.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5/ext/websocket-driver
make DESTDIR\= clean
current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5/ext/websocket-driver
make DESTDIR\=
make failedNo such file or directory - make

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/bundle/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/bundle/extensions/aarch64-linux/3.1.0/websocket-driver-0.7.5/gem_make.out
```

The following command solved my problem

```
apt install -y build-essential
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when installing rails, but I solved it by running the command: `gem install rails` without adding `sudo`.

Comment: But if you don't add `sudo`, you don't have permission to install gems...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my machine doesn't have `make` and `cmake` install yet (which need to be build package, cfile, etc...), so it gem can't be install rails

```bash
sudo apt install cmake make
```

Then

```bash
sudo gem install rails
```