# Failed to Build Gem Extension Error Installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm on a fresh Ubuntu installation and using the guide to install rails found [here](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html).

When I get to the final `sudo gem install rails`, I get this error:

```
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-1.2.1/ext/nio4r
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160821-19665-u7rxlt.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-1.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nio4r-1.2.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: first try `gem install bundler`

Comment: There are missing headers for ruby. Apt get install ruby2.3-dev

Comment: Please add the contents of `cat /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nio4r-1.2.1/gem_make.out`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
gem update --system 2.0.3
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17657242/4132578