# Can't install Rails on linux: “Failed to build gem native extension” with ruby 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, amazon-ec2, yum

I am trying to install rails on an amazon-linux instance, but I keep getting the same error reported [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655806/error-when-installing-ruby-on-rails-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension):

```
[ec2-user@xxx.xxx ~]$ sudo gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.3/gems/nokogiri-1.7.2/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170529-26560-9zyb13.rb extconf.rb
```

Note that I manually upgraded ruby to 2.3

```
[ec2-user@xxx.xxx ~]$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

I've also tried with another versions of rails (I'd like to install the latest, 5.1.1), with also no luck

```
sudo gem install rails --version 5.1.1 --no-ri --no-rdoc
sudo gem install rails --version 5.0.0 --no-ri --no-rdoc
sudo gem install rails --version 4.2.8 --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Is this possible at all or do I need to downgrade ruby to 2.0?

Comment: Have a look at RVM

Comment: Also did you tried `gem update --system 2.0.3`

Answer (score 5):

It seems the error occurred while compiling nokogiri.

The [nokogiri docs](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#ubuntu___debian) says

> Troubleshooting Ubuntu / Debian Installation
>
> If you have issues, first make sure you have all the tooling necessary to compile C extensions:
>
> 1. sudo apt-get install build-essential patch
>
> It’s possible that you don’t have important development header files installed on your system. (This has never happened to me personally, but I have it on good authority that otherwise good and noble Ruby developers run into this.) Here’s what you should do if you should find yourself in this situation:
>
> 2. sudo apt-get install ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev