# make: /usr/bin/mkdir: Command not found during `gem install nokogiri` in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, makefile, rubygems, nokogiri

I already installed all neccessary libraries it couldn't found (libxslt-dev, libxml2-dev), specified `-- --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2 --use-system-libraries`, but it still fails with

```sh
make "DESTDIR=" install
make: /usr/bin/mkdir: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:202: .sitearchdir.-.nokogiri.time] Error 127
```

Comment: It's a poor makefile if it includes hardcoded paths for utilities like that.  it should simply rely on the user to set their PATH correctly, else it's inherently non-portable.

Comment: @MadScientist Of course poor, especially if you can't change it (like here)

Comment: @MadScientist It turns out that this path is detected when Ruby is compiled, and that value is assumed when any Gem is compiled.  So it's not hard-coded per se, but it is set at Ruby build time, not Gem build time.

Ubuntu incorporated an upstream change somewhere between 20.04 and 20.04.1 that moved `mkdir`.  RVM's Ubuntu binaries are built on 20.04, so if you try to use them on 20.04.1, you will get this error for all gem installations.  See https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4975.

You can work around the issue with `rvm reinstall 2.7.2 --disable-binary` (substitute desired version).

Comment: IMO even hardcoding this fully-qualified path into a Ruby environment is a bad idea.  Relocatability is a very useful feature.  There's really no point in this.  That's what PATH was invented.

Comment: Seems to affect rbenv, too. Reinstalling, or better, bumping from ruby 2.7.3 to 2.7.4 resolved it for me.

Comment: This Q is closed, unfortunately, but worth mentioning that the accepted answer fixes  an error in GitHub actions: `racc` install error: `make: /usr/bin/mkdir: No such file or directory`. Simply use the accepted answer: `run: |
          ln -s /bin/mkdir /usr/bin/mkdir
          gem install bundler
          bundle config path vendor/bundle
          bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`sudo ln -s /bin/mkdir /usr/bin/mkdir`

Comment: I'm getting operation not permitted for this command
`% sudo ln -s /bin/mkdir /usr/bin/mkdir`
`ln: /usr/bin/mkdir: Operation not permitted`